# PHP reading a 3rd party dynamic excel file using PHPExcel/PhpSpreadsheet

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

I have a dynamic Excel file that was created by a 3rd party.
The file connects to the 3rd party servers and is data refreshed every second.

I'm trying to extract relevant data from it, and I tried to use **PHPExcel** and **Phpspreadsheet**.
I worked with PHPExcel before and it works great for me on static files, but in this case, I can't seem to get the results I need.

When I tried **PHPExcel** to extract the data using this:

```
$worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(6,4)->getValue() ;
$worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(6,4)->getCalculatedValue() ;
$worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(6,4)->getFormattedValue() ;
```

I got the error:

**Error: PHPExcel_Calculation_Exception: Formula Error: Unexpected ,**

Also tried to use:

`$worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(6,4)->getOldCalculatedValue() ;`

that method return data, but I don't get to current data I get something that looks like default data that don't update and stay the same no matter what I actually see in the excel file.

I tried to switch to **Phpspreadsheet** I get the same result as I got on the `getOldCalculatedValue()` by using this method:
`$data->sheets[0]['cells'][4][5]`

I believe That if I'll find a way to copy the excel file with the values (no formulas) I can bypass the issue I'm facing (because it will be like working with static files), but I want to avoid that because I need my script to extract the data every second and I want to make minimum actions needed as possible.

**EDIT**

I searched alot and only now found this link for the same issue:
[Extracting dynamically changing data in excel via php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062398/extracting-dynamically-changing-data-in-excel-via-php?rq=1)

It basically says that it can not be done by PHPExcel because in order to do so the file must be saved to get the current data.
So the option is to create a copy of it and save it.
Also, they refer to this link:
https://marcelwijayacc.wordpress.com/2011/09/22/obtaining-live-data-feed-from-excel-or-any-windows-object-using-php/

Comment: it's obvious that there are a problem in your cell content. what is the output of `$worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(6,4)->getOldCalculatedValue() ;` ?

Comment: the value is ok by its cell format but the value is not updated and stays the same, no matter what the excel file shows. for example, if I have a cell with a numeric value and its current value on the excel sheet is 2500, I will get the value 2200 and I will continue getting the same 2200 value no matter how many times the cell value changes.

Comment: How is the file dynamically updated? I I don't think PHPExcel/PhpSpreadsheet can handle dynamically loaded cells like that.

Comment: The file is a product of a 3rd party and there is a service that sends requests to the 3rd party servers and they are updating the data locally on the excel file. I don't know exactly how and what they do behind the scenes.